# nswag generated client with wrong response type

Tags: c#, angular, nswag

This is autogenerated Angular service file from C# controller with help of nswag swagger client generation. This below code has all the services. In component i am trying to call getCompanyInfoOption() api. But i am not getting response data that i am sending from controller.

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NSwag toolchain v13.6.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.18.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)) (http://NSwag.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

import { mergeMap as _observableMergeMap, catchError as _observableCatch } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError as _observableThrow, of as _observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBase } from '@angular/common/http';

export const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');

@Injectable({
providedIn:'root'
})
export class CompanyInfoService {
    private http: HttpClient;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "https://localhost:44311";
    }

    getCompanyInfoOption(): Observable<FileResponse | null> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/company-info";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "application/octet-stream"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processGetCompanyInfoOption(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processGetCompanyInfoOption(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<FileResponse | null>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<FileResponse | null>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processGetCompanyInfoOption(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<FileResponse | null> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob =
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body :
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }}
        if (status === 200 || status === 206) {
            const contentDisposition = response.headers ? response.headers.get("content-disposition") : undefined;
            const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition ? /filename="?([^"]*?)"?(;|$)/g.exec(contentDisposition) : undefined;
            const fileName = fileNameMatch && fileNameMatch.length > 1 ? fileNameMatch[1] : undefined;
            return _observableOf({ fileName: fileName, data: <any>responseBlob, status: status, headers: _headers });
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<FileResponse | null>(<any>null);
    }
```

how can i call this service in my component? i am trying to call with subscribe method in ngOnInit of component

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.service.getCompanyInfoOption().subscribe(
        value => {
          console.log(value);
        },
        error => console.error(JSON.stringify(error)),
        () => console.log('done')
      );
  }
```

I am getting this output after calling getCompanyInfoOption api

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s2YA.png)

My c# controller

[ASP .net core C# controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvtda.png)

The type of response of compantInfoOption send in ok is given below

[conpanyInfoOption type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLsP7.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is something wrong with the generated code, because your controller return type isn't correct, try using [ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#actionresultt-type), then the generated api will return the proper result instead of expecting a file response.

in your case

```
public async Task<ActionResult<CompanyInfoOptionAc>> GetCompanyInfo(){
//etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, you are right in controller my return type should be Task<ActionResult<CompanyInfoOptionAc>>

Comment: I would suggest updating the question title so others can find it when they are looking for it, something like, nswag generated client expecting a file response or nswag generated client with wrong response type. I am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are. Because you response type is `FileResponse` and in console.log you may see this object. Other thing that in data you store `blob` and if you need a text interpretation if it just use smth like `blobToText` function which is in the end of your generated file.

If I'm wrong please add expectation result to the question.

Comment: how will i get expection result?

Comment: you need to get it out from blob or use json

Comment: in controller my return type was wrong thats why error was occuring